# Is there anyway to use a full stop in a variable name

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I was just wondering if there was a way to use

```
public test.name as string
```

I know that the full stop usually  allows access to sub sections of things but me and a friend where wondering if there was an actual way to allow it

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` operator is used to access traits of a class. Because of this, you cannot have it in a variable name. If you did, how could the compiler tell the difference between the `.` in your variable, and the `.` when you actually want to use it as an operator?

Answer (score 1):

No, since the period is already being used by the language, as you said, as a unary operator.